# Sass list separators and writing a clean @mixin

Tags: css, sass, namespaces, scss-mixins

I have a `@mixin` that allows me to name-space selectors. The code is below:

```
@mixin pre-assign($value) {
  $pre: $value !global;
}

@include pre-assign('foo');

@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace +
      str-replace(
        str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)),
        $search,
        $replace
      );
  }

  @return $string;
}

@mixin pre($value) {
  $result: '';

  $result: str-replace($value, '.', '.#{$pre}-');

  #{$result} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

I can use the `@mixin` as follows:

```
// declaration
@include pre('.bar + .baz') {
  display: none;
}

// output
.foo-bar + .foo-baz {
  display: none;
}
```

I want to tidy up the way that I pass selectors to the `@mixin` and omit the quotes, so that I am not passing selectors as string values:

```
@include pre(.bar + .baz) {
  display: none;
}
```

However, when I attempt to do so, I am met with the following error:

> ERROR in ./lib/all.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./lib/all.scss)
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> `@include pre(.bar + .baz) {
>               ^`
>
> Invalid CSS after "@include pre(": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".p--compact) {"

I suspect this is something to do with the `$list_separator`, but am not sure how to achieve this. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't achieve this with selectors like `>`, `+`, `<`, as it will be interpreted as an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really feel the need to not use strings, you could put your operators in a map; [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/dba30533b5a1c560a3c3d1b5e0b4203b)

### CODE

```
$operators: (
  adjacent: '+',
  general: '~',
  universal: '*',
  child: '>',
  descendent: ' '
);

@mixin namespace($list...) {
  $selector: '';

  @each $arg in $list {
    $index: index($list, $arg);
    $val: if($index % 2 == 1, '.#{$pre}-#{$arg}', map-get($operators, $arg));
    $selector: $selector + $val;
  }

  #{$selector} {
    @content
  }
}
```

### USAGE

```
@include namespace(cool, adjacent, stuff) {
  color: green;
}

@include namespace(cool, general, stuff) {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these responses. Between both answers I got what I was looking for :)

Comment: happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the operators need to be strings. But you can pass the selectors without strings. [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/448c045d5e1ff7288c9cc1026367277e)

### Code

```
$pre: ;

@mixin namespace($args...) {
  $selector: '';

  @each $val in $args {
    $index: index($args, $val);
    $selector: $selector + if($index % 2 == 1, '.#{$pre}-#{$val}', ' #{$val} ');
  }

  #{$selector} {
    @content
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
@include namespace(cool, '+', stuff) {
  color: green;
}

@include namespace(stuff, '~', things) {
  color: red;
}

@include namespace(stuff, '*:not(.lame)', things) {
  color: red;
}
```